# iPhone: maximumElapsedTimeForCachedLocation used to remove cache value of core location

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, core-location, cllocationmanager

In certain cases, cached values are immediately returned when starting a location service. Any location with a time interval older than this value will be considered invalid.

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSTimeInterval maximumElapsedTimeForCachedLocation
```

Declared In

```
UABaseLocationProvider.h
```

Do any of you know how to use this maximumElapsedTimeForCachedLocation in Core Location for removing the cache value of the old location?

Comment: Noone knows how to implement this?